# Document Feathering Tolerance on Drawing

Tags: manufacturing-engineering, machining, technical-drawing, drawings

I am recreating an engineering drawing package from old quotes for a large assembly. In the quote they say "All length edges not to exceed 1/32" deep feathering". For some context this is for a bunch of graphite blocks which were cut to a constant cross-section.

First what exactly does feathering mean in this machining context? Secondly what is the best way to denote this tolerance on an engineering drawing?

Answer (score 1):

Could they possibly be referring to surface finish? If they are, its called surface roughness, denoted as a value "Ra"

[image]